# how to pass parameter name "action" in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can not send parameter name "action" by url in asp.net web api 2.0.

Example:

> http://host:port/controller_name?action=2&...

if you do so:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{action}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    action=RouteParameter.Optional
                }
            );
```

method in controller:

```
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(int action)
    {
        return ResponseXml();
    }
```

gives an error message:

> in the dictionary path name of the parameter "action" is contained in
>   the URL-address more than once

How to pass parameter name "action" as a parameter, rather than the action method ?

thanks

Comment: If you want to your action param through querystring(?action=..), then you don't need to set in the route map. In your current routeTemplate, your url should be like /controllername/actionname/xyz, but if that is reqriured, why can't you change your routeTemplate to use other than action?

Comment: @Karthik M R I need to receive data strictly according to the protocol which format: **http://host:port/controller_name?action=2&login=**, first parameter should be parameter name "action"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the name action is included in the querystring part(?action=2), no need to change the route map. The framework will bind the value to the action paramter in the action method. Remove the extra {action} in routeTemplate. And since your url format  doesn't contain {action} host:port/controller_name?action=2&login=, remove {action} from routemap.
So, your route map will be

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id=RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

Comment: if you do so, receive an error: _No action was found on the controller 'Values' that matches the name '2'_ .Because is a binding parameter value to the method controller

Comment: remove api from routeTemplate. have updated my answer

Comment: its clear. Thanks. I thought that all the parameters should be strictly specified in the route.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) and include it in the route template.

```
//GET [controller_route]/2
[HttpGet]
[Route("{action:int}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int action)
{
    return ResponseXml();
}
```

which will let you use the following url

```
http://host:port/controller_name/2
```

where `action` parameter will be mapped to `2`.

Remember to enable the attribute routing during configuration.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```